# symbolic and numerical division, sqrt with the same code

Tags: python, sympy

I have a code expression like

```py
def div(a, b):
    return a / b
```

that I would like to return `a / b` *symbolically* if I call the function with an `int` or a sympy expression, i.e.:

```py
from sympy import Rational, sqrt

compute(1.0, 7.0) == 0.14285714285714285  # (1)
compute(1, 7) == sympy.Rational(1, 7)     # (2)
compute(1, sqrt(2)) == 1 / sqrt(2)        # (3)
```

The definition above does the numbers (1) and (3) right, but returns the float `0.14285714285714285` for (2). This

```py
def div(a, b):
    return Rational(a, b)
```

doesn't work with (1) and (3) at all.

On top of division, I'd love to know how to get this to work for `sqrt` as well.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are not SymPy type so you get Python division. Try:

```
def div(a, b):
    from sympy import S
    return S(a) / b
```

(Handling `a` will have the effect of handling `b` during the division.)